# NSException: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason:..."

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

this is coming from an iPhone app written in swift:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', 
reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, 
and [UICompatibilityInputViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1836984d0 0x198107f9c 0x183698418 0x188d7a1d0 0x188d833dc 0x188d83354     
0x188d81e3c 0x188cfe8fc 0x188cfdc0c 0x184581220 0x188cfda90 0x188d0ad08 
0x1895558e4 0x189556944 0x188d11af8 0x189556740 0x1895505d4 0x188dccd90 
0x18939b3dc 0x18939b5ec 0x18d43bb20 0x18d43bea0 0x18364fd6c 0x18364f800 
0x18364d500 0x18357d280 0x18e6f40cc 0x188d6adf8 0x100120d94 0x19894a8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm building an that app that requires the phone to be held  'PortraitUpsideDown,' so that the rear-camera is always on the bottom.  To reflect this, my Info.plist includes:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
```

That app is small and has a single view controller, which includes

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
   return false
}
```

The app terminates somewhat spontaneously.  I am able to build and use the application for varying amounts of time, i.e. I have not been able to "cause" the error to occur.

Comment: Does your app contain input view like text edit?

Comment: No, just a camera interface a lot like that of SnapChat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orientation is determined by three files:

1. Info.plist
2. view controller(s)
3. AppDelegate

`Info.plist` must include

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
```

`ViewController.swift` must contain

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown
    }
```

`AppDelegate.swift` must contain

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown
}
```